# Python: Getting error while manipulating dictionary and JSON (string indices must be integers, not unicode)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

My code is as follows
 **Contents of dict1 and dict 2 are printed below in output**
This code is part of my program in which dict1 and dict2 are generated by program only and fed as input to this piece of code.
When I just run bellow fragment of code as a separate program by explicitly declaring dict1 and dict2 it works perfectly. While when I use this code fragment in my program where dict1 and dict2 auto generated it throws error as given in output. 
 
**Note:** The program creates new dict with K(value of dict2):v(value of dict1) where keys of both dict same.

```
print dict1
print dict2
def walk(dict1, dict2):
    output = {}
    for key, value in dict1.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            output[dict2[key]] = walk(value, dict2)
        else:
            output[dict2[key]] = value
    return output


output = walk(dict1, dict2)
print output
```

**Output is:**

```
{u'one': u'ele-ven', u'-two': u'twe.lve'}    #This is dict1
{"one": "red", "two": "blue"}                   # this is dict2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "z.py", line 68, in <module>
output = walk(my_data, dictionary)
File "z.py", line 62, in walk
output[dict2[key]] = walk(value, dict2)
File "z.py", line 64, in walk
output[dict2[key]] = value
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not unicode
```

**Expected O/P is**

```
{u'red: u'ele-ven', u'blue': u'twe.lve'}
```

**OR a json string will also do like**

```
{"red": "ele-ven", "blue": "twe.lve"}
```

Comment: Just tried your code using Python 2.7, and I got `KeyError: u'-two'`, but not TypeError.

Comment: you might have tried above code cardcoding dict1 and dict2, that way it works on my side.   But when I use this code inside another programs where dict1 and dict2 auto generated I get type error... Very strange :-(

Comment: Are you sure it's real dict and not string? Try `print type(dict1)` and check the output.

Comment: Yes that was trick, dict2 is the JSON string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict2` is apparently not a dict at all, but a string; presumably JSON. You probably need to parse it first: `dict2 = json.loads(dict2)`.

Comment: Spott On fella. Somebody else has also given me this hint and he asked me to check type of those dicts, Dont know why he deleted his answer. 
After converting JSON to dict its working perfectly fine. Thanks :-)

However, When I hardcode that dict1(dictionary format) and dict2(JSON string format) the program runs just fine.  Dont know what the mistry is.